# seaborn lineplot time-series indicating trend in activity

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

On a `seaborn` lineplot, I would like to indicate trend in a time-series data, preferably using different colours.

For example, taking this fake data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=50), columns=['max'])
df['day'] = pd.date_range('2016-1-1', periods=50, freq='SMS')#freq='W')
df['date'] = df['day'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

On a `lineplot` this produces the following figure:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df, x = df['date'], y='max', )
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

[image]

So I would like to indicate the trend in time series between `2017-01` and `2017-08` such that the plot's background in this area is in green, with begin and end marked (similar to the figure below, but inserting green background in the area indicated).
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ax.axvspan`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan.html):

```
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x = df['date'], y='max', )
ax.axvspan('2017-01', '2017-08', color='g', alpha=0.1)
```

output:

[image]

alternative with a different `zorder`:

```
ax.axvspan('2017-01', '2017-08', color='g', alpha=0.5, zorder=0)
```

output:

[image]